# Mongoose query not showing subdocument

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I can't get mongoose to show subdocument when running find() while it displays perfectly well in mongodb shell.

Subdocument should be embedded based on my schema, not objectId referenced, so I shouldn't be running any black magic voodoo to get my data to show up.

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String;
  xp: Number;
  //etc.
});

const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  status: { type: String, enum: ["pending", "ongoing", "completed"]},
  players: {
    type: [{
      points: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      position: String,
      user: UserSchema
    }],
    maxlength:2
  }
});
```

After adding a new room with:

```js
let room = new Room(coreObj);
room.players.push({
  points: 0,
  position: 'blue',
  user: userObj //where userObj is a result of running findById on User model
});
```

It displays nicely in mongo shell, when running db.rooms.find({}).pretty() I can see that full document has been added. However, when running on mongoose model:

```js
Room.find({}).exec((err,rooms)=>{
  console.log(rooms[0].toJSON()); 
});
```

I don't see user subdocument, moreover I cannot see user field entirely! What seems to be the problem?

logged json from mongoose model:

```
{
    "status": "pending",
    "_id": "5cf5a25c050db208641a2076",
    "timestamp": "2019-06-03T22:42:36.946Z",
    "players": [
        {
            "points": 0,
            "_id": "5cf5a25c050db208641a2077",
            "position": "blue"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

json from mongo shell:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cf5a25c050db208641a2076"),
        "status" : "pending",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-03T22:42:36.946Z"),
        "players" : [
                {
                        "points" : 0,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5cf5a25c050db208641a2077"),
                        "position" : "blue",
                        "user" : {
                                "xp" : 0,
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5cf2da91a45db837b8061270"),
                                "username" : "bogdan_zvonko",
                                "__v" : 0
                        }
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "don't see user subdocument"? Please post what you see when you print it to the console.

Comment: @kevinadi I updated the question accordingly. Any thoughts to steer me in right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping best practice in mind, I think it would be more appropriate to reference the `UserSchema` in the `RoomSchema`.  Something like:

```
...
user: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'UserSchema'
}
```

Then you would store the `user._id` in that field.

This way, if the user is modified, your `RoomSchema` is always referencing the correct information.  You could then get the user using Mongoose's `populate`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, will probably edit it out like this. As rooms are only temporary I thought it would be easier to just embed the document as it would make queries easier (and faster?) Do you know maybe why this strange behavior is occurring, how can the same query give different results in mongoose and mongodb shell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you can't see the sub-sub-document, but this code example printed it correctly for me. Example was originally posted in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html but modified slightly to contain sub-sub-document so it looks similar to your code:

```
var grandChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });

var childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', grandChild: grandChildSchema });

var parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ children: [childSchema] });

var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);

var parent = new Parent({
  children: [
    { name: 'Matt', grandChild: {name: 'Matt Jr'} },
    { name: 'Sarah', grandChild: {name: 'Sarah Jr'} }
  ]
})

parent.save(function() {
  Parent.find().exec(function(err, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res[0]))
    mongoose.connection.close()
  })
});
```

Executing this code resulted in:

```
{
  "_id": "5cf7096408b1f54151ef907c",
  "children": [
    {
      "_id": "5cf7096408b1f54151ef907f",
      "name": "Matt",
      "grandChild": {
        "_id": "5cf7096408b1f54151ef9080",
        "name": "Matt Jr"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cf7096408b1f54151ef907d",
      "name": "Sarah",
      "grandChild": {
        "_id": "5cf7096408b1f54151ef907e",
        "name": "Sarah Jr"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

This was tested using Mongoose 5.5.12.

Note that I was using `JSON.stringify()` to print the document instead of using Mongoose's `toJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just met a very similar problem, i think i got it.
the whole point is in model which you use:

```
const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
 players: {
   type: [{
      ...
      user: UserSchema
      ...
```

but then you make

```
room.players.push({
  points: 0,
  position: 'blue',
  user: userObj //where userObj is a result of running findById on User model
});
```

so you are missing the "type" subfield, so your doc is not compliant with your RoomSchema and mongoose do not show the parts which does not fit schema.

Answer (score 0):

This code Works from the official Docs of Mongoose [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html)

```
// Subdocument definition
interface Names {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  firstName: string;
}
// Document definition
interface User {
  names: Names[];
}

// TMethodsAndOverrides
type UserDocumentProps = {
  names: Types.DocumentArray<Names>;
};
type UserModelType = Model<User, {}, UserDocumentProps>;

// Create model
const UserModel = model<User, UserModelType>('User', new Schema<User, UserModelType>({
  names: [new Schema<Names>({ firstName: String })]
}));

const doc = new UserModel({});
doc.names[0].ownerDocument(); // Works!
```